# Preformatted child content stretches parent grid cell

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a CSS grid element and one of its cells contains some preformatted code (`<pre><code>...</code></pre>`). This code can have some long lines and smaller screen widths may not be able to fit the whole line. However, I don't want to line break because this could mess up certain code like:

```js
console.log('test'); // Log the me
ssage
```

`<pre>` and `<code>` do this automatically, however they do not apply a scrollbar. Instead the content overflows the parent. To address this, I tried adding `pre { overflow-x: auto; }`, which can show a scrollbar. However this still stretches any parent grid cell to fit the underlying long `<code>` block, even if it is contained in a fixed width `<pre>` tag which makes no sense to me.

See this minimal example where I reproduced this issue.

```css
#grid {
  display: grid;
  /* Should split the page in half. */
  grid-template: 'left right' 100% / 1fr 1fr;
}

#left {
  grid-area: left;
}

#right {
  grid-area: right;
}

pre {
  /* For long content, horizontal scrollbar should appear. */
  overflow-x: auto;

  /* If we forcibly shorten `pre` width, the scrollbar appears, but grid is still stretched by the `code` element. */
  /* width: 50%; */
}

#tall {
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="grid">
      <div id="left">
        <div>Some content on the left.</div>
        <div>This should scroll with the single vertical scrollbar. </div>
      </div>
      <div id="right">
        <pre>
          <code>Some very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long code content.</code>
        </pre>
        
        <div id="tall">Some very tall content</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I tried a minimal example of a grid with two columns of equal sizing. One of those columns contains a long `<code>` tag. This is fine for screens large enough to fit the content, but for smaller screen sizes the `<code>` tag stretches its cell beyond its half of the screen and the grid grows beyond its container as well and forces a horizontal scrollbar on the grid. Even if I force `overflow-x: auto;` on the `<pre>`, the `<code>` tag still stretches the grid as long as it needs. The other column is shrunk to compensate and almost the entire width is dominated by this one `<code>` tag. This is very undesirable but I can't find a way to fix it. What I want in this example is for the grid to *always* be split 50/50 between the two columns. If the screen is too small to fit the long `<code>` text, then a horizontal scrollbar should appear on the `<pre>` or `<code>` tag and the grid should *always* match the viewport width and *never* have a scrollbar.

This image hopefully demonstrates what happens when the viewport width is too small. The two column layout is no longer split down the middle and a scrollbar appears at the bottom of the grid (the two red marks). Instead I'm trying to keep the split in the middle of the grid and have the scrollbar *only* under the code content in the right column.

[image]

Inspect element shows me that the `<pre>` tag is sized correctly. If I apply `width: 50%;` to it, I can see that it is smaller than its containing grid cell. However the `<code>` tag always extends to its full line length. I think that's kind of expected, however I would think the `overflow-x: auto;` on the `<pre>` tag should avoid that length pushing on the grid cell. Am I missing something here? I've tried fiddling with `width`, `max-width`, `overflow-x`, and `white-space` in as many ways as I can figure out.

I've also managed to [reproduce this with flexbox](https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-fqutfm?file=index.html,styles.css), so I don't think it's specific to grid. Is this some quirk with `<code>`, `<pre>`, or `white-space: pre;`?

Comment: Your question needs to be understandable without any external links. That means you need to include your minimal reproducible example code as part of your question, preferably as a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/2518285).

Comment: Ok, copied the Stackblitz into a stack snippet if it really helps that much.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not about answering a question for one person only — it is about building a database of questions and answers with timeless relevance. External links cannot be guaranteed to work into the future, that is why there is a requirement for the relevant code to be included in the question. I have initiated the process of reopening the question. Once that process is complete, the community can contribute answers.

Answer (score 0):

You need the grid cell to scroll any overflow, not the code. Instead of styling the `<pre>` tag with `overflow: auto`, style the `#right` cell with it instead.

```css
#grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

#left {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#right {
  border: 1px solid lime;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid">
  <div id="left">Some content on the left.</div>
  <div id="right">
    <pre>
      <code>Scroll me sideways. Some very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long code content.</code>
    </pre>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So my example might have been a little too minimal. In reality I have more content under `#right` than just a single `<code>` (it's really a markdown document). Putting `overflow: auto;` on `#right` wouldn't be desirable because the horizontal scrollbar goes at the bottom of `#right`, which is at the bottom of the page, far away from the `<code>` tag the user is actually trying to see.

I updated my example to be more clear about this, but in the process ended up solving the problem in a slightly different way. I posted an alternative answer, though I don't understand exactly why this works.

Answer (score 0):

While updating the example to address Brett's answer, I managed to accidentally solve this problem, though I still don't understand how.

The trick is to add `#right { overflow-y: auto; }`.

```css
#grid {
  display: grid;
  /* Should split the page in half. */
  grid-template: 'left right' 100% / 1fr 1fr;
}

#left {
  grid-area: left;
}

#right {
  grid-area: right;
  
  /**
   * IMPORTANT for some reason?
   * #right isn't (and shouldn't be) scrollable, but this is needed for `pre` to get its scrollbar.
   */
  overflow-y: auto;
}

pre {
  /* For long content, horizontal scrollbar should appear. */
  overflow-x: auto;

  /* If we forcibly shorten `pre` width, the scrollbar appears, but grid is still stretched by the `code` element. */
  /* width: 50%; */
}

#tall {
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="grid">
      <div id="left">
        <div>Some content on the left.</div>
        <div>This should scroll with the single vertical scrollbar. </div>
      </div>
      <div id="right">
        <pre>
          <code>Some very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long code content.</code>
        </pre>
        
        <div id="tall">Some very tall content</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This doesn't really make sense to me though because `#right` isn't scrollable (and shouldn't be). No matter how small the viewport, or how big its content, `#right` never gets a scrollbar. Instead the `<html>` tag gets the scrollbar. I was really trying to put the scrollbar on `#grid`, but in this particular case the grid is the whole page so it really doesn't matter for me even if it wasn't exactly what I was trying to do. This also updates the `pre` tag to respect its `overflow-x: auto;` and get its own horizontal scrollbar.

Interestingly, `#grid { overflow-y: auto; }` actually has no effect. `overflow` *must* be set on `#right`, even though it triggers a scrollbar on `<html>`. I've never seen `overflow` on a child element either:

1. Put a scrollbar on a parent.
2. Allow a scrollbar on a child.

I feel like `#right` is the exact *wrong* place to put `overflow-y: auto;`, but it appears to be necessary. If anyone can help me understand why this is the case, I would be eternally grateful.

Aside: I considered that adding `overflow` to `#right` might be necessary to create a new [block formatting context (BFC)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context) to get the `pre` tag to layout independent of `#grid`. However, I don't think this is the case because MDN calls out [`display: flow-root;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display#flow-root) as a non-side effectful way of creating a new BFC. However, attempting to use `#right { display: flow-root; }` does *not* have the intended effect and the `pre` tag still don't get its own scrollbar. So I have to assume that means `#right { overflow-y: auto; }` is doing something else to fix the problem, I just have no idea what that something is.